# To find all positive integers $n$ such that $n|a^2-1 ; a \in \mathbb Z \implies n|a-1 $ , or $n|a+1$

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

How do we find all positive integers $n$ such that $n|a^2-1 ; a \in \mathbb Z \implies n|a-1  $ , or $n|a+1$ ? I have found that for any odd prime $p$ and $n \in \mathbb Z^+$ , $p^n|a^2-1 ; a \in \mathbb Z \implies p^n|a-1  $ , or $p^n|a+1$  and that $2|a^2-1 \implies 2|a-1$ , or $2|a+1$ are these all the possible $n$ ?

Comment: $gcd(a-1,a+1) = 1$ or $2$ depending on $a$. $4|a^2 - 1$ might mean $4$ divides one of $a-1$ or $a+1$ else $2|a-1$ and $2|a+1$ is possible as well.

Comment: Try proving that if $p$ and $q$ are odd primes, one can find an $a$ that gives a counterexample.

Comment: Also try to prove that $2p$ satisfies your conditions

Comment: @JefLaga: Oh yes , you are right ;  $2|a-1$ iff $2|a+1$ so since $p$ divides one of $a-1,a+1$ and $2$ divides one of them too so also the other ; we get $2p$ must divide one of them , given $p$ is odd . But I don't understand your $p,q$ comment ; if $n$ is not a prime power does not necessarily mean it is a product of two distinct primes ; or am I misunderstanding ?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Let $n\gt 1$ be odd and not a prime power. Then there exist relatively prime integers $k\gt 1$ and $l\gt 1$ such that that $n=kl$.

By the Chinese Remainder Theorem the system of congruences $x\equiv 1\pmod{k}$, $x\equiv -1\pmod{l}$ has a solution.

If $a$ is a solution, then $a^2\equiv 1\pmod{n}$, but $a\not\equiv 1\pmod{n}$ and $a\not\equiv -1\pmod{n}$.

**Remark:** In conjunction with the work you have already done, it only remains to deal with even $n$. 
A similar idea will work, except when $n$ is $2$, $4$, or of the form $2p^e$ for an odd prime $p$. If you have already seen primitive roots, the pattern will be familiar.

Comment: @dezakin: I had just typed a comment to the effect that a question about the cardinality of the number of models, suitably restricted (up to isomorphism, underlying set a fixed countably infinite set, language with finite number of non-logical symbols) could be quite interesting, when you deleted the question so I coud not post the comment.